# How to use conda to install Github package specutils?

Tags: python, github, conda, astropy

I am using Anaconda python (2.7) on my Windows 7 machine. I want to install [specutils](https://github.com/astropy/specutils) which is a associated package for Astropy.

conda, as I understand, can installs binaries using `conda install <package>` command. My question is

- where can I find the binary version of the specutils in the above cited repository.
- How do I install specutils using conda?

Answer (score 2):

You can install [`specutils`](https://github.com/astropy/specutils) with conda:

```
$ conda install -c astropy specutils
```

This installs specutils from the [astropy anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/astropy/specutils/files) (I'm almost certain that you can find the binaries there). If you want to install the development version you can also use:

```
$ pip install git+https://github.com/astropy/specutils.git@master
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no stable releases of specutils yet, but you can install it by doing:

```
git clone https://github.com/astropy/specutils.git
cd specutils
python setup.py install
```

The specutils docs can be found [here](http://specutils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/specutils/index.html), and please report any issues [here](https://github.com/astropy/specutils/issues)